# Python - How to extract text between two variables in a big text

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm kinda new to Python and I decided to automatically collect the menu of my canteen. I don't want to use chrome driver so I planned to use requests but I can't properly collect only the menu of the current day and have to take the menu for all the week.
So I have this text with all the menus and want to extract the part between the current day and the next one. I have the variables with the current day and the next one but don't know how to do then.

Here is what I did:
(The thing I can't fix to get the text is at the end when I use re.search)

```
from datetime import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

url = "https://www.crous-lille.fr/restaurant/r-u-mont-houy-2/"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

def getMenu():
    #This gives us the date number without the 0 if it starts with it
    #i.e 06 october becomes 6 october
    day = datetime.now()
    day = day.strftime("%d")
    listeD = [int(d) for d in str(day)]

    if listeD[0] == 0:
        listeD.pop(0)

    strings = [str(integer) for integer in listeD]
    a_string = "".join(strings)
    pfDay = int(a_string)

    dayP1 = pfDay+1 #I have to change the +1 because it doesn't go back to 1 if the next day is a new month
    #I'm too lazy for now though

    #collect menu
    data = soup.find_all('div', {"id":"menu-repas"})
    data = data[0].text
    result = re.search(r'str(pfDay) \.(.*?) str(dayP1)', data) #The thing I don't know how to fix
    #The variables are between the quotes and then not recognized as so
    print(result)

getMenu()
```

How should I fix it?
Thank you in advance ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.get_text()` method. The current day is first `class="content"` under `id="menu-repas"`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.crous-lille.fr/restaurant/r-u-mont-houy-2/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

print(soup.select_one('#menu-repas .content').get_text(strip=True, separator='\n'))
```

Prints:

```
Petit déjeuner
Pas de service
Déjeuner
Les Plats Du Jour
pizza kébab
gnocchis fromage
chili con carné
dahl coco et riz blanc végé
poisson blanc amande
pâtes sauce carbonara
Les accompagnements
riz safrane
pâtes
chou vert
poêlée festive
frites
Dîner
Pas de service
```